# Is it possible to create docs for multiple packages within the same git repository with sphinx-apidoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, namespace-package, sphinx-apidoc

I have a git repository which includes multiple packages which follow a namespace (i.e [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

I am trying to create a ReadTheDocs documentation using Sphinx.

The git repository looks like this repo: https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages

In order to test this on my local machine, I'm using Sphinx's docker image `sphinxdoc/sphinx`.

I have tried to use different ways to generate the documentation for all of my packages, but each ends up with a different problem.

### sphinx-apidoc

`docker run -it -v` pwd`:/repo --rm rtd bash -c 'make clean && rm -rf /repo/docs/_source/* && sphinx-apidoc -F -o /repo/docs/_source /repo && make html'`

The problem with this is that it will generate wrong packages as `sphinx-apidoc` uses the subfolders to generate the packages, which is wrong. This will end up with `pkg_resourcespkg_a.example_pkg.a` which does not exist and should actually be `example_pkg.a`

### autoapi.extension

```py
# conf.py
def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package, "--no-deps"])


rootfolder=os.path.abspath('../')
add_module_names = False
autoapi_dirs = []
pathlist = Path(rootfolder).glob('repo-*/repo/*/')
for path in pathlist:
     path_in_str = str(path)
     autoapi_dirs.append(path_in_str)
     print(path_in_str)

...
...

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary', 
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
    'autoapi.extension',
    'sphinx_rtd_theme',
]
autoapi_type = 'python'

autodoc_mock_imports = [
    'tensorflow',
    'flask',
    'numpy',
    'plotly',
    'tqdm',
    'StringIO',
    'lime',
    'vis',
    'efficientnet_pytorch',
    'pycocotools',
    'repo.trainer.self_trainer_model',
    'theano',
    'sklearn',
    'torch',
    'telegram',
    'msvcrt',
    'bs4',
    'livereload',
    'repo.common.config',
    'plotting_server',
    'experiments',
    'cropper',
    "anytree",
    "skimage"
]
```

I have also tried this, but unfortunately, this ends up without showing anything about my packages in the HTML while also throwing the following warnings:

```
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/data/characteristics/detection/kmeanboxes/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/data/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/data_structure/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/detection/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/generators/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/inference/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/mine/repo_eye_naveyaar/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/mine/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/mine/miner_vieweryoungweedscropped/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/trainer/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/utils/dataset_specific/repoeyeweedsbackgrounds/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/utils/dataset_specific/repoeyeweedslabdetection/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repo/utils/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repocommon/repo/common/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repodatasets/repo/data_sets/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repometrics/repo/metrics/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repomodels/repo/models/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/repooptimizers/repo/optimizers/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/repo/docs/autoapi/index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

So, my question is if it is possible to create docs for multiple packages within the same git repository with sphinx-apidoc?

Comment: autoapi is an extension that is unrelated to sphinx-apidoc. If you have a problem with it, post a separate question.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but perhaps you can try https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#cmdoption-sphinx-apidoc-implicit-namespaces

Comment: @mzjn unfortunately using --implicit-namespaces will only work for a specific package, e.g /repo/package-a/namespace. I'm trying to generate docs for /repo/package-*

Answer (score 1):

After quite some digging I figured few things which weren't clear to me while posting my question:

1. `sphinx-apidoc` is limited only for python and might be tricky to use as it actually imports the python code, which might require installing dependencies or mocking them using `autodoc_mock_imports`.
2. `sphinx-autoapi` works with more programming languages as stated on [its documentation](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx-autoapi) and does not require installing dependencies.

However, in order to create the documentation for multiple packages within the same git repository with either sphinx-apidoc or sphinx-autoapi, I had to add the following code to `docs/conf.py`:

```
from glob import glob
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

currentfolder = os.path.abspath('./') # aka docs/
rootfolder = os.path.abspath('../')
tmpfolder = "{}/tmp".format(currentfolder)
globdir = '{}/repo-*/repo'.format(rootfolder)
subprocess.check_call(["mkdir", "-p", tmpfolder]) # make sure temporary folder exists 

all_sub_dir_paths = glob(globdir) # returns list of sub directory paths
for subdir in all_sub_dir_paths:
    print("subdir: {} to tmp folder: {}".format(subdir, tmpfolder))
    copy_tree(subdir, tmpfolder) # copy all folders to docs/tmp/repo/*

autoapi_dirs = [tmpfolder]
sys.path.insert(0, tmpfolder)
autoapi_python_use_implicit_namespaces = True
```

This solution will copy all of the packages within the repo to a temporary folder, which will allow the docstring tool to scan and then generate the relevant docs.

I have ended up using sphinx-autoapi, but it did work also with sphinx-apidoc which might require you to install these packages:

```
def install(package):
     subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package, "--no-deps"])

def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in dirs:
            if name.startswith('repo-'):
                l = "{}".format(os.path.join(root, name))
                # print("Added to path: {}".format(l))
                sys.path.insert(0, l)
                install(l) # might no be required 
        break # stop os.walk recurssion
    return r
list_files(currentfolder)

autodoc_mock_imports = [
    'tensorflow',
    'flask',
]
```

You can debugging this locally using docker:

```
docker run -it -v `pwd`:/repo --rm rtd bash -c 'python -m sphinx -T -E  -d _build/doctrees-readthedocs -D language=en . _build/html'
```

If you are using ReadTheDocs Business, all you have to do is to push your code to the relevant branch and the rest will happen automatically for you.