# Create single Sphinx documentation page on readthedocs.org from multiple Python repositories

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have an open source project split into different repositories, which I would like to document on a single readthedocs page (using, for instance, `sphinx.ext.autosummary`). For now, the Sphinx `conf.py` and the master toctree document are contained in a separate `docs` repo:

```
docs
├── index.rst
├── conf.py
└── ...
foobar
├── foo
│   └── __init__.py
└── bar
    ├── __init__.py
    └── baz
        └── __init__.py
```

Building the Sphinx documentation locally, I could simply download all repositories and [use relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45953127) to direct Sphinx to the different repositories, e.g.:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../foobar'))
```

However, this won't work building the project at readthedocs.org. I searched, but found only [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66186901) that *"(copies) all of the packages within the repo to a temporary folder, which will allow the docstring tool to scan and then generate the relevant docs."* [In a variation of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17217041), symlinks are to be used.

This is likely not the optimal solution. Am I missing some basic functionality of Sphinx?

Comment: There might be someone with more experience to give you an answer. What I found so far is to deploy each component to its own site and then use a reverse proxy to bridge the URLs together (for https://www.pysnmp.com).

Comment: A fairly complex example of what we do in Plone can be found at https://6.dev-docs.plone.org/contributing/setup-build.html and you can skip the step for PyEnchant. This repo pulls in three others via git submodules and `make`. It's pretty nifty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Read the Docs configuration option `submodules` to pull down other Python repositories and use the same trick `sys.path.insert` that you commented when building locally.

So, you would need to:

1. add the git submodule via `git submodule add https://github.com/me/project/`
2. commit and push the changes
3. use `submodule` option in Read the Docs configuration file (see https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#submodules)

```yaml
version: 2

# ...

submodules:
  include: 
    - project
```

4. trigger another build on Read the Docs and it will hopefully work :)

Let me know if that works.